# Need someone help with 2 sentences in this context [Manga/MC's thinking about his battle strategy and how it will affects to people lives]

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

Context : MC and A-san have thought out a strategy/plan to defeat the enemy. Now MC and A-san is marching on the main road ,with their army and the armed people/militia of their town ,toward enemy's castle.Much thanks if anyone can explain to me the correct meaning of his thoughts here o/

A-san「この作戦で、大丈夫かな……」
"Hey I'm wonder will everything be alright ,with this plan/strategy..."

MC: 「大丈夫だってば。二人でしっかり考えた作戦だし……きっと上手く行くって」
"I told you,it'll work.It's a strategy that we have thought out thoroughly together...
I'm sure things will go smoothly."

そうは言うけど、もちろん自信なんかあるわけがない。
I said that to her,but of course I don't have any confidence.

**人事を尽くして天命を待つ……なんて言うけど、掛かってるのはみんなの命だ。それじゃダメなのはわかってるけど……。**
We did what we can,now we'll just have to wait for fate to decide...or so I'd like to say,
but what I'm dealing with here are everyone's lives.I know that I should not have that kind
of mentality but...

**MC（……俺のミスで人が死ぬっていきなり言われても……こんなの、どうしろっていうんだよ）**
(...I mean,even if I'm suddenly being told that people died because my mistake...
What am I supposed to do about it ?)

> > These bolded parts are the 2 sentences I'm not quite sure about what he has been thinking.

Comment: Welcome to JLSE! This sounds an awfully lot like a [translation request](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799), which is probably why you got a downvote. In order to get a good answer, you might want to explain what you don't understand about the sentence, and maybe say how you understood the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am interpreting this as a translation request, so I'll translate these sentences based on context.

1. 「人事を尽くして天命を待つ……なんて言うけど、掛かってるのはみんなの命だ。それじゃダメなのはわかってるけど……。」⇒ "I'll do the best I can and wait for destiny... or so I say, but it's everyone's lives that are on the line. I know that's no good, but..."

「人事を尽くす」roughly means "do everything in my power." Since 「して」follows this phrase, it means to do what I (or we) can to wait for destiny　(天命)。「掛かっている」means "on the line".

2. 「……俺のミスで人が死ぬっていきなり言われても……こんなの、どうしろっていうんだよ」⇒ "If someone suddenly told me that people would die because of my mistakes, I wouldn't know what I should do about that."

I'll need more context to clarify some parts, but it sounds like a lot of doubts on the MC's part.